# web-scraping vwap value for list of stock in data frame

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, stock, stockquotes

scraping particular value (vwap) from nse web site:
here i have a data frame with stock list , i need to fetch the vwap value for every stock from nse website .
below is the reproducibe code .

```
    stock_list = ['SKIPPER','NIPPOBATRY','RANEHOLDIN','OSWALAGRO','GINNIFILA','VOLTAMP','NACLIND','GALLANTT','ASAHISONG','KSL','UNICHEMLAB',
'TRENT','TIL','MMP','SHARDAMOTR','ARCHIES','MAGADSUGAR']
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['stock_list'] = stock_list
df['vwap_value'] = 0
```

[image: As shown in the image highlited with yellow area to fetch and insert into respective vwap column]

**How to scrape vwap value again the stock name specified in the data frame**

`https://www1.nseindia.com/index_nse.htm`

so In the above url once this url is called after that `SKIPPER` from the first stock_list would be entered in the EQUITY search box and  new url page be navigated

`https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=SKIPPER&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0` and then vwap value would be fetch from the new link.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: @AndrejKesely i have added the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is embedded within the page in Json format, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can use `json` module to load it.

For example:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=SKIPPER&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#responseDiv').text)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print('averagePrice:', data['data'][0]['averagePrice'])
```

Prints:

```
averagePrice: 45.52
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the stock name in URL to get HTML page for each stock:

`https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=<stock_name>&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0`

With each page, you get the vwap value by this code:

`vwap = response.xpath("//span[@id='vwap']).xpath("string()").extract()`